# What is error mysql (#1356)?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-grant

I create a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AuthorizationTrainer AS 
  SELECT Person.id, Person.login as nick, Person.password as pass 
  FROM TABLE2,Person 
  WHERE TABLE2.id_Person = Person.id
```

Then create grants:

```
GRANT SELECT ON Teachprog.AuthorizationTrainer TO 'Trener'@'%'
```

`SELECT id,nick FROM AuthorizationTrainer` - works

`SELECT id,nick,pass FROM AuthorizationTrainer`  - produces the error:

> fly error: #1356 - View `'Teachprog.AuthorizationTrainer'` references invalid table(s) or
>            column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the grants on the underlying `TABLE2` and `Person` tables? You can grant all the select permissions you want on the view, but if the user is blocked from accessing the `pass` field in `Person`, you'll get this error. To check:

```
show grants for trener@%
```

Comment: Person and Table2 have permission to select

Answer (score 0):

Grant user trainer permission to select the table. you have only given grant for view.

```
grant select on Teachprog.TABLE2,Person to 'Trener'@'%' ;

grant select on Teachprog.Person to 'Trener'@'%' ;
```